# I want to make a txt into a dict in python

Tags: python, dictionary

so i have the following data:

```
Apples = 1
Bananas = 1
Box_Cashew = 
{ 
    Cashew = 1
}
Dragonsfruit = 2
Crate_box_epox=
{
    box_epox = 
        {
             epox = 2
        }
}
```

and want to make a Dictionary from this txt, as it follows:

```
{'Apple':'1' , 'Bananas' : '1' , 'Box_Cashew' : {'Cashew':'1'} , 'Dragonsfruit' : '2', 'Crate_box_epox' : { 'box_epox' : {'epox':2}}}
```

i tried read line by line with the code below, but i dont know what to do when i got a dict within a dict.

edit:

@PrestonM and @juanpa.arrivillaga

The text file:

```
unit=9023
state=1411
flags=
{
    1NobelChemistry=yes
    1NobelLiterature=yes
    1NobelMedicine=yes
}
worldmarket=
{
    worldmarket_pool=
    {
        ammunition=204.50766
    }
}
```

The code:

```
text_file = open("teste.v2", "r")
lines = text_file.readlines()
d={}
for line in lines:
        try:
            (key1, val) = line.replace('\t','').replace('\n','').split('=')

            d[str(key1)] = val
        except:
            pass
```

result:

```
>>>d
{'unit':'9023' , 'state':'1411' , 'flags':{},'1NobelChemistry':'yes' , '1NobelLiterature':'yes' , '1NobelMedicine':'yes','worldmarket':{},'worldmarket_pool':{},'ammunition':'204.50766'}
```

desired result:

```
>>>d
{'unit':'9023' , 'state':'1411' , 'flags':{ '1NobelChemistry':'yes' , '1NobelLiterature':'yes' , '1NobelMedicine':'yes'},'worldmarket':{'worldmarket_pool':{'ammunition':'204.50766'}}}
```

Comment: How does this text come to be?

Comment: Can you post the code that you have?

Comment: Edit your question to include the code please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following seems to work in my tests. I hope the comments and text in the exceptions makes it clear what's being done.

In your code, you're simply adding everything to the same dictionary, which cannot produce the result you're after. As soon as `{` is encountered, you want to start adding key/value pairs to a new dictionary, that's actually stored in the old dictionary. To accomplish this, the code below keeps track of these dictionaries in a list, adding one if necessary, and removing one from the list to get back to the previous dictionary.

```
dictStack = [ { } ]
currentKey = None
for l in lines:
    l = l.strip() # Remove whitespace at start/end
    if not l: # skip empty line
        continue

    if l == "{":
        if currentKey is None:
            raise Exception("Current key not set!")

        newDict = { }
        dictStack[0][currentKey] = newDict
        dictStack.insert(0, newDict)
        currentKey = None
    elif l == "}":
        if currentKey is not None:
            raise Exception("Current key is set, expecting {")

        if len(dictStack) == 1:
            raise Exception("Can't remove the final dict, there seems to be an extra '}'")
        dictStack.pop(0)
    else:
        if currentKey is not None:
            raise Exception("Current key is set, expecting {")

        if not "=" in l:
            raise Exception("Expecting '=' in '{}'".format(l))

        key, value = l.split("=")
        key, value = key.strip(), value.strip() # remove whitespace
        if not value:
            currentKey = key
        else:
            dictStack[0][key] = value


if len(dictStack) != 1:
    raise Exception("Still more than one dict in the stack")

result = dictStack[0]
```

Comment: Thanks @brm your comments in the code really helped!

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution which uses recursion:

```
import re

def text2dict(text):
    def f(ls, i):
        d = {}

        while i < len(ls):
            if ls[i]=="}":
                return d, i

            m = re.match(r"(.*)=(.*)", ls[i])
            k = m.group(1).strip()
            v = m.group(2).strip()

            if not len(v):
                v, i = f(ls, i+2)
            d[k] = v
            i += 1
        return d
    return f([l.strip() for l in text.split("\n")], 0)

with open("file.txt") as f:
    text = f.read()
print(text2dict(text))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def make_dict(text):
    l = "{"
    t = text.splitlines()
    for j,i in enumerate(t):
        if i != '':
            line = i.replace(" ", "").split('=')
            next = t[j + 1].replace(" ", "").split('=')[0] if len(t) > (j + 1) else "}"
            if line[0] == "{" or line[0] == "}":
                l += line[0]
            else:   
                l += ("'"+line[0] + "':" + ("'"  + line[1] + "'" + ("," if next != "}" else "") + "" if line[1] != '' else ""))
    l += "}"            
    print(l)            

make_dict(text)
```

Result:

```
{'unit':'9023','state':'1411','flags':{'1NobelChemistry':'yes','1NobelLiterature':'yes','1NobelMedicine':'yes'}'worldmarket':{'worldmarket_pool':{'ammunition':'204.50766'}}}
```